# Class has invalid expression term "from" when querying using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, serialization

I have the following serializable class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailClass
{
    public string from;
    public List<string> To;
    public List<string> CC;
    public string DisplayTo;
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int attachments;      
    public List<string> attachmentsName;
    public string DateTimeReceived;
    public string DateTimeSent;
    public string FinalFilename;
    public string DatetimeCreated;
    public string ExchangeUniqueId;
    public string ChankeyID;
    public string  FinalFileName {get;set;}
    public bool Encrypted;
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

}
```

So know, I have a List and I want to query it  using Linq:

```
 var query = from p in listado 
             where p.from.ToString().ToUpper() == textBox1.Text
```

And the problem is that it recognizes the `p.from` **as the linq from identifier**, so it
is not accepted.

> Error: Invalid expression term 'from'

I **can not** change the class public string "from" because it is deserializing
xml objects stored in hard disk.

How could I work around this problem?

I know I could use List.FindAll or something like that, but I would really
like to know if I can do it using linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David Arno has shown how to avoid conflicts with keywords via `@from`, however:

> I can not change the class public string "from" because it is deserializing xml objects stored in hard disk.

As an alternative approach:

```
[XmlElement("from")]
public string From {get;set;}
```

This tells `XmlSerializer` how to map the name; then you can use:

```
var query = from p in listado 
            where p.From.ToUpper() == textBox1.Text
```

Comment: My answer was the "quick fix". Yours is "best practice" long term solution. +1 for not being lazy like me :)

Answer (score 8):

Change `where p.from.ToString()` to `where p.@from.ToString()`. You are using `from` as both a keyword and identifier.

Comment: Thank you dude. I will accept answer as soon as system allow me.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas, I'd recommend accepting Marc's rework of how your XML is de-serialised to an object as the correct answer, for IMO it's a better answer than mine.

Comment: Ok, I'll listen to you. Thanks for your contribution anyway!

Answer (score 1):

you could use the method chain instead:

```
var query = listado.Where(p => p.from.ToString().ToUpper() == textBox1.Text);
```